# jQuery dynamic HTML attributes overwriting script

Tags: jquery, css, contains, dynamic-html

I have been struggling for a few days now working with jQuery trying to write a script that replaces dynamically created span style colors from a chatbox of a forum.
Both elements are wrapped inside a `td` element with `class="chat"` and a    span with `style="color:green"` like this

```
<td class="chat"><span style="color:darkgreen;">test</span></td>
```

The scripts I tried to write for instance (that did not work sadly);

```
$(".chat:contains('darkgreen')").css("color", "rgb(255, 111, 7)");
$(".chat:contains('darkgreen')").css("font-weight", "bold");
$(".chat:contains('darkgreen')").css("text-shadow", "bold");
$(".chat:contains('darkgreen')").css("text-shadow", "rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 1px 1px");
$(".chat:contains('darkgreen')").css("text-shadow", "rgb(255, 111, 7) 1px 0px 6px");
```

I've also tried changing the class "chat" with a few other classes like `td`, `chat` but none of them worked either way, any ideas how can I make it work with jQuery even after a new `td` & class is being generated by the chatbox to change their desired span color with my CSS?

Comment: Missing a dot there: `$(".chat:contains` - also try `$(".chat>span[style='color:darkgreen;']")`

Comment: I tried adding a dot regarding that class, also excuse me for missing three semi-colons at the end of the last three lines but it did not work still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it via

```js
$(".chat>span[style='color:darkgreen;']")
.css({
  "color":"rgb(255, 111, 7)",
  "font-weight": "bold",
  "text-shadow": "bold",
  "text-shadow": "rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 1px 1px",
  "text-shadow": "rgb(255, 111, 7) 1px 0px 6px"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="chat"><span style="color:darkgreen;">test</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tried the script you wrote but it didn't change anything, I am using Tampermonkey to apply the jQuery code, could it be me targeting the URL not correctly? Refreshing the page I'm trying to apply the code to changes the colors sometimes but it happens rarely and whenever I type something into the chatbox, the effect is lost and it doesn't overwrite the new span.

Comment: Update: your code seems to be working amazingly well, the only problem left is the script itself not applying the changes always to the web page, refreshing it or switching to another chat tab loses the whole effect and after a new message is being generated in the chatbox, the jQuery script doesn't apply the changes to it.

Comment: The you need to post more code that show when and how you apply it. You need to apply it using delegation

Comment: I managed to fix the code, all I had to do is fix the right targeting element and then it would execute the script fine without using delegation, thank you for the solution!